# How to read a flat file without footer row using Informtica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm working on a workflow where i have to read a flat file without Footer row. How to handle this row without breaking the file structure using Informatica. Please find the sample data given below.

HEADER, FILE.TXT, 2018-20-11 
"COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4" 
"Dave","123-456-7890", "Charlotte", "NC" 
TRAILER,1

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: After reading the file you can filter out the record where COL1='TRAILER'

Comment: Sorry, there is a double quote as text qualifier for the data and column names. I have already tried the logic you have mentioned.

Comment: But why that would be an issue?

Comment: Hi Sam, I have applied the logic that you suggested however its not working as expected for some of the mappings. The issue is if the field that we are using in the filter condition has all null values the filter condition is not working as expected. I have tried passing '' value for all the null values still no luck.

Comment: You can try the ISNULL function

Answer (score 0):

Won't pretend I've done it myself but following post outlines removing quotes... Nico is usually spot on so consider the approach he suggests along with the filter Samik mentioned

https://network.informatica.com/thread/9404

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command to read the file. Just need to change the `Input Type` Source Qualifier property on a session from `File` to `Command` and put `head -n-1 yourFileName` as the `Command`.
That should to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can avoid reading footer line, but you can eliminate footer line(s).
If the file structure is consistent you can use just Filter transformation to filter out on "TRAILER,1". 
If not you can try this approach:

```
SD > SQ > AGG[+ v_cnt Count(COL1)]
             [+ o_dummy=1)       ] > JN (Join by v_dummy) > FIL (where o_seq < v_cnt) > TGT
        > EXP[+ v_seq=v_seq+1    ] >
             [+ o_seq = v_seq    ]
             [+ o_dummy = 1      ]
```

After Source Qualifier "split" stream to Aggregator and Expression transformations.
In Aggregator add two ports:

1. v_cnt for counting all rows in a file and
2. o_dummy port to keep hardcoded value ("1") for joining back with the second stream.

And in Expression transformations add three new ports:

1. v_seq for assigning sequential number.
2. o_dummy port to keep hardcoded value ("1") and
3. o_seq output port that returns v_seq.

In Joiner join these two streams by v_dummy = v_dummy and set ports from aggregator as Master (for performance).

If there are empty rows at the bottom, after footer row, you can add another filter (better after SQ) to filter out empty lines… Actually, you can eliminate as much footer lines as you need by filtering `o_seq < v_cnt -N`